# Javascript VM object returned has wrong reference?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

Back again with another tedious problem. It's easier if I explain the context before the problem. I'm trying to build a project (in Node.JS) that allows you to program itself, from inside itself via an "input" (this could be network/console or anything really, but lets assume via a console for this).

So let's imagine we have an object:

```
var database = {
    'test': 123
}
```

Now from the console I type:

```
;database.myFunc = function() { return database.test; }
```

I run this using `vm.runInContext` and copy it back into the database object afterwards (it needs to be sandbox'd because it's non-privileged users running it). This works fine, and the code works fine when executed in the next command:

```
;database.myFunc()
=> 123
```

All good so far. Now at this point I built my own object dumper that can export functions as strings (`var str = new String(database.myFunc)`), which works and exports them as strings.

This issue comes when I import the code from a file. I've tried code like this:

```
code = "retval = " + data.toString();
sandbox = vm.createContext({
    "database": sb.database
});
result = vm.runInNewContext(code, sandbox);
sb.database = result;
console.log(sb.database.myfunc());
```

It appears the code that runs, only has access to the database i copied into the sandbox. This isn't what I want, I want it to access the same DB it had at the first runtime. Any suggestions as to how I'd do that?

Comment: After a bit more fiddling, I realised I can pass the database object as an argument. Which is fine, apart from I want to pass multiple variables like this and don't want a massive argument list, and callbacks I can't alter will fail.

Answer (score 0):

As the name implies, `vm.runInNewContext` creates a different context every time you call it. So don't use that! Instead, use [`vm.createContext`](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_createcontext_initsandbox) (once only) with [`vm.runInContext`](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_runincontext_code_context_filename). You'll need to maintain a reference to the `context` returned by `createContext()`.

Comment: This seems like the solution i'm looking for. I was hoping to be able to do something like this upon execution of a command (from the user):

    sandbox = vm.createContext({
        "database": userIsRoot ? database : database.userSpace[user]
    });

How would you go about doing this?

Comment: I'd make `database.userSpace` a function.

Comment: and how would I determine the user who programmed the function, as the function may be called by another user.